# C executable not finding library after build

Tags: c, macos, shared-libraries, dyld

I'm getting started with C on a Mac, and I just built a library outside my project and tried to use it.
I passed the `-I` and `-L` flags in the Makefile and the project built successfully and generated the executable, but when I tried to run it, it's looking for the library in the wrong places.

`hello.out` is the name of the executable

> dyld[78926]: Library not loaded: libmurmurhash.so
> Referenced from: /Users/xxxxx/code/C_C++/test_project/hello.out
> Reason: tried: 'libmurmurhash.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libmurmurhash.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libmurmurhash.so' (no such file), '/Users/xxxxx/code/C_C++/test_project/libmurmurhash.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libmurmurhash.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libmurmurhash.so' (no such file)

Are there any other flags I should pass?

When I put the `.so` file within the project directory, the executable runs without any problems.

Not sure what I missed, I also exported the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the path of the lib.

Comment: The `-L` is only for the compiler search. While I'm not sure why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` wouldn't work, seemingly you can correct this with the `-rpath` flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726993/how-to-specify-preference-of-library-path (StefanB's answer)
Edit: In regards to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it could be your cache has not been reset. You could try following directives from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758828/purging-and-rebuilding-ldconfig-cache

Comment: The loading mechanism for dynamic libraries on macOS is a bit different from what you find on, e.g,  Linux. I can never remember the details, so I won’t try to explain them, but spending some time poring over the output of `man dyld` might be a good idea. In particular, I *think* you want `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but don’t take my word for that...

Comment: (Also: dynamic libraries are usually named `.dylib` on macOS, so the fact that yours are named `.so` is an indication that the build system of that library isn’t quite adapted to macOS...)

Comment: exporting  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to the library path worked!.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: Image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found)